# This site can’t provide a secure connection – ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: windows, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

i have a website its open source developed using asp.net core. and its already deployed on windows server 2019 and iis 10, my problem is when request the web site from my country(Jordan) its working like a charm,my problem is when request the web site from certain ISP in Germany its not working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvn6T.jpg)

any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pasyona.de&latest) your site has an IPv6 and and IPv4 address but SSL is only configured properly for IPv4. Given that IPv6 is the preferred protocol today browsers will attempt to use it if possible. The ISP you've tried so far likely did not provide IPv6 connectivity so that the connection succeeded. The ISP where it fails likely provides IPv6 connectivity.

The fix is of course either to configure both IPv4 and IPv6 properly or to make sure that your domain name does not resolve to an IPv6 address.

Comment: Thank you very much, problem fixed as you told me